# In my system i ve logged in as Admin user, but cant able to acces d: therough commend line

Tags: path

In my system i ve logged in as Admin user, but cant able to access d: through commend line. For example when i open cmd its showing

```
C:\Users\Admin
```

I tried to change the path to 
    D:

```
C:\Users\Admin cd D:
```

It shows

```
C:\Users\Admin cd D:   
D:\   
C:\Users\Admin
```

But i need it as

```
C:\Users\Admin cd D:   
D:\
```

What should i do?

Comment: Please be aware that Stack Overflow is for questions on programming problems. You may be able to get better help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this command : `D:` ?

Comment: I ve tried it it showing 
  
    'D:\' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please try only `D:`

Comment: Simple D: is working, thanks shruti

Comment: @shruti1810: Please don't fight for it. I'm sorry, but the question is off-topic for SO and will hopefully be deleted...